# How to change the order of widgets?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13

i'm just getting started with Magento Enterprise and i have been given a existing Magento website to modify. They just want me swap two of the widgets that are aligned along the left side of their webpage.

I turned on Template Path Hints in the options menu to find where the widgets were located.. but i guess that's not what i'm looking for? what would i need to edit in order to swap the first widget's location with the second? also if you could include steps or simple instructions that would be great!

Thanks in advance for any help! Any and all help is appreciated! Even just tips to working with Magento Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the location of the widget in xml. After getting both widget you can check for its name. 
Say you have two widget widget1 and widget2. You want widget2 after widget1 so what you need to do is you need to add in the xml for widget2 `after="widge2name"` for example

```
<block type="abc/abc" template="abc/abc.phtml" name="widget1"/>
<block type="abc/abc" template="abc/abc.phtml" name="widget2" after="widget1"/>
```